# How to calculate at runtime the maximum value allowed before datatype rollover?

Tags: c++, structure, sizeof, packing

I have the following structure:

```
struct Some_Struct {
    uint32_t a;
    int16_t  b;
    uint8_t  c;
};

struct Other_Struct {
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint32_t c;
};
```

The variable size is being calculated as such:

`uint32_t size = sizeof(Some_Struct) + sizeof(Other_Struct) * n;`

My question is, given a `sizeof` Some_Struct and Other_Struct whose actual size is dependent on the platform, architecture, and packing, how can I at runtime determine the maximum number of `n` allowed before `size` rolls over?

Comment: "as specifying [0] is undefined." - That's not quite exactly correct. Use a _flexible array member_: `Other_Struct e[]`. That `[1]` hack is legacy and invokes undefined behaviour in modern C.

Comment: This is only supported by C99. C++ which is tagged also does not support flexible array members.

Comment: With the above notes i guess its time to ask the question yet again, is this `c` or `c++`? They are not the same language and will not have the same answer.

Comment: Well, C standard is C11, nothing else. And whoever uses ancient C should move on; it's 17 years obsolete now. About C++: That's a different language and you should not use such constructs in C++ at all! Please restrict your question to **one** language. C and C++ are **not** compatible!

Comment: Updated the question as it concerns C++. I am working on a legacy codebase which used `[0]` everywhere. In an effort to cleanup compiler warnings I've adjusted them to `[1]` and have been correcting declarations accordingly. This question relates to some code I found along the way.

Comment: Another note: sending a raw `struct` over a network (or marshalling it directly in general) is a very bad idea. It does not account for padding, endianess, etc.

Comment: You are correct but I'm not addressing this issue at the present time. My question is very specifically regarding calculating the valid range for `n`.

Comment: My comment above implies the valid range: the valid range for `n` is exactly `1 ... 1`. Well, you can allocate more, but just must not access anything else than `.e[0]` with your approach.

Comment: The question has been updated.

Comment: Unclear about the validity of `uint32_t size = sizeof(Some_Struct) + sizeof(Other_Struct) * n;` should alignment requirements affect things.  Posting the application of `size` would add value and clarity to the post.

Comment: Any changes to the maximum limit due to alignment is not being considered as the current implementation has a laundry list of problems. This is just a patch which adds logging of a rollover where it was previously being cast and truncated. One impossible task at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [numeric_limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/):

```
uint32_t maximum_n = (std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() - sizeof(Some_Struct))
                                / sizeof(Other_Struct);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be: `uint32_t maximum_n = (std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() - sizeof(Some_Struct))
                            / sizeof(Other_Struct);`

Comment: Ah, you're right--I misunderstood your equation. I thought you had parentheses around the `sizeof`'s.

Comment: Edited to match

Comment: Thanks for your help. Makes perfect sense.